# Google Analytic: Only include traffic that has visited a particular page

Tags: google-analytics

I want to only view traffic in Google Analytics that has visited a certain page at any point during their session.  It doesn't matter if it's the landing page, the second page, the third page, etc. They just need to have visited a particular page at some point during the session.

I have attempted to do it using a custom segment as follows:
create new segment--> advanced --> conditions --> visits --> Page --> contains --> [required url]

I have to questions
1) Will this segment do what is intended? I.e. Have I set it up correctly to only view traffic that visited the intended page at some point. 
2) Is there a way to do this using a custom filter rather than a segment?

Comment: yes that segment looks right. re: custom filter: filters in a custom report won't do this, that's what segments are for. Filters on a view level do something completely different, they are NOT the same as segments. They control whether or not data is kept or tossed permanently, instead of just showing subsets of data

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant or not.  But there is a difference between ga:pagepath and ga:pageTitle.  You might want to take note of this.

Comment: @CrayonViolent, thanks for your reply.  Yes, I was specifically wondering if it's possible to create a view filter that would only keep traffic that has visited those pages and permanently toss out everything else. Is it possible to create such a filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `View` in Google Analytics existing `property` and add a `filter` to include only data for `Request URI`.

> Admin > Create New View : > View Settings > Filter > Include > Filter Field : Request URI > Field Pattern : Use a regex or exact url > Done.

The data in the View would be filtered as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.