# Google Analytics: Create a View that excludes all users who visited a particular URL?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to create a view with filters in Google Analytics that excludes data from all users who have visited a particular URL? Eg. `Site.com/internal/`

I am aware of creating segments but was wondering if it is possible to do this by creating a separate View with filters because it is a cleaner solution for my current situation.

**What I have tried**

[image: f my]

The above solution does not seem to work. I still have Events that fire (as shown in the real-time view) even though I previously visited `Site.com/internal/`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With that filter you exclude visits to pages that contain `/internal/`. If you have created the filter recently you have to wait for tomorrow to see today's data filtered (even if you currently see it in real time).

What you can try to do id send a value in a session-level custom dimension when someone visits /internal/ and exclude sessions with that value.

Comment: Does this exclude all activities done by a user (eg. pageviews to other pages not containing `/internal/`, e-commerce transactions, events, goals) as long as they visited `/internal/`? Or does it only exclude pageviews to `/internal/`?

Thanks.

Comment: The second one.

Comment: Thanks. Then can you please suggest a way for me to do the first one?

I did this method because someone else seemed to be able to exclude traffic just using URI (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772937/google-analytic-only-include-traffic-that-has-visited-a-particular-page)? Not sure if I misunderstood the post there.

The objective here is that all team members will visit `/internal/` before testing other sections of the site and so in the view, we want to exclude all their activities so that we can see clean data from external visitors.

Comment: The answer in the link you indicated will not work, I don't know why it has a green tick.
What you can try to do is send a value in a session-level custom dimension when someone visits /internal/ and exclude sessions with that value. I updated my answer.